my MUI DatePicker is controlled but not working as expected
I'm using:
@mui/x-date-pickers: 6.18.2

I'm trying to control my DatePicker every time I'm picking a date above, a week from now the state doesn't change but datepicker UI changes to the date selected, how can I fix it so the UI date will be the state date?
import * as React from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { DemoContainer } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/demo';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';

export default function DatePickerValue() {
const now = dayjs()
const weekFromNow = now.add(1,'week')
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(now);

const handleChange = val => {
if(val > weekFromNow ){
alert('asdasd')
return
}
setValue(val)
}

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DemoContainer components={['DatePicker', 'DatePicker']}>
        <DatePicker label="Uncontrolled picker" defaultValue={dayjs('2022-04-17')} />
        <DatePicker
          label="Controlled picker"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </DemoContainer>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

I'm trying to control my datepicker.

It looks like you are trying to validate the user-selected date with this if-condition: if(val > weekFromNow ).
There are two problems with this:

Dayjs date objects should be compared using Dayjs comparator functions (e.g. isAfter()), not using a greater-than (>) operator.
If your goal is to prevent users from selecting invalid dates, and your range of valid dates can be expressed using a minimum and/or maximum date(s), you probably should be using DatePicker built-in validation. This prevents users from selecting invalid dates, and avoids using an if-condition for validation. Try the maxDate DatePicker prop with your weekFromNow constant instead of using your if-condition. This should prevent the date picker interface from highlighting an invalid date since the user cannot select it.

